# Single word for 'set difference'? possibly latin

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

Quite a while ago I heard my Lecturer refer to the set $\mathbb{Z}$ \ { $0$ } as "Z 'son' zero" (meaning Z without 0). I think I think must have misheard the 'son' as, after a lot of googling, I can't find any references to it meaning the set difference. Does anyone know the word I'm looking for? I would imagine it was some latin word meaning to remove.

I know its not the most interesting 'maths' question but it has me intrigued

Comment: In French and in Spanish, "a" is pronounced just the "o" in "top" is spoken. The answerer below nailed what you're looking for.  So what your Lecturer was saying is likely "Z sans zero".

Comment: thanks for confirming this. I'll be sure to use it at any opportunity to impress people :)

Comment: Splendid!  (I had a professor who would refer to anything subscripted with $0$, for example $A_0$,  as "A-nought", (nought pronounced like "naught" as in "naughty")

Comment: @amWhy: The *o* in *top* in most varieties of **American** English is similar to Spanish *a*; in most varieties of British English the vowel of *top* is fairly poor match for any Spanish *a*. And the nasalized *a* in French *sans* is also very different from Spanish *a* and the American *top* vowel; apart from the nasalization it actually comes closer to the British *top* vowel.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, @BrianM.Scott.  I know Spanish, and my first language is of course American English.  I was relying, I guess, on the similarity in (I guess primarily in) the written Latin Languages.  I was simply trying to match how what was heard was "$Z$ son zero."  Oh well, probably too much speculation/overgeneralization on my part.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps 'sans' (French for without).  $\mathbb{Z}$ without $0$.

Comment: I think your spot on.

Comment: yes this certainly seems to fit. Thank you